# Symfony 2 CRUD: Is there a standard way to auto-secure the generated controllers?

Tags: security, routes, symfony, crud

All the controllers generated by the command "doctrine:generate:crud" are by default accessible in all the enviroments (ie: dev, test, prod)

How would you go about not forgetting to secure this controllers on production? I mean this is scary

The only thing I came up with is to use a secured prefix for the crud routes, and always remember to use that prefix when generating the controllers.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only really "clean" way of handling this requirement is to blacklist access to *all* your routes via security.yml, and whitelist those which you want to be accessible.